# .htaccess Multiple rewrites?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I want to rewrite to multiple pages.

I want an request to mysite.com/home to be rewritten to mysite.com/home.php and a request to mysite.com/u/erty5000 to be rewritten to mysite.com/profile.php?u=erty5000 using a .htaccess file.

Is this possible? And if it is, how?

So far this is how I rewrite request from mysite.com/home to mysite.com/home.php

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1.php [L,QSA]
```

Thanks in advance! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the first rule. You must exclude the `u/...` request however. Add a [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond), which does this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/u/
```

The second rewrite works similar. Extract the needed part from the request and use it in the substitution

```
RewriteRule ^u/(.+)$ /profile.php?u=$1 [L,QSA]
```